# How can i make a custom command execute when the command is typed in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am making a program which sends notes to diffrent people on a page.
for constructing the note i use the editor tinymce.
i want the note to be send upon entering :send at the end of my tekstarea, but when i do, it will only run if i put text after my command.
how do i execute the :send upon pressing the last letter (d)?

here is my code:

```
 tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea:not(.noMCE):not(.textArea)',
    menubar: false,
    height: 50,
    statusbar: false,
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists preview table autoresize mention,textpattern",
    ],
    textpattern_patterns: [
        {start: ':send',cmd: 'send'},

    ]
```

and then my send command:

```
 setup: function (ed) {
        console.log(ed);
        // Register example command
        ed.addCommand('send', function () {

            alert('hi');
        });
    }
```

Comment: That is not how the textpattern plugin works...you can always make a copy of it and customize it to work as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to implement your own textpattern plugin to do what you're describing. Currently this is out of scope for how it works.